# R Install Packages Undable to Access Repository

Tags: r

I'm new to R, and I'm trying to install the "Reshape" package, but I get this error

```
install.packages("reshape")
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2
Warning message:
package ‘reshape’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

I've searched around, seems this should definitely be available for download, but I can't figure out whats causing the issue

Comment: Does it work for any other packages?

Comment: ...or any other mirrors?

Comment: no I've just tried another few packages same error, not being able to access the repository seems to be the main issue. Do I need to do something beforehand to make a connection? I only downloaded R recently so it should be on all the default setting

Comment: most likely either (1) you have a generic network connection problem (do you have any problem reaching other sites?) or (2) some sort of proxy setting problem, e.g. see http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/uninstalled-and-reinstalled-R-now-cannot-install-packages-td4697720.html

Comment: Try `download.file` on some things that work in your browser. I reckon its a https problem, so try http and https links...

Comment: @ErikRasmussen   `setInternet2(use = TRUE)` perhaps. That has solved the issue for me in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem... I went to the Default CRAN Mirror to an HTTP mirro and that seems to have resolved it.

I hope this helps you too.

Felipe

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same error message. I got it with loading other packages too, but after I downloaded the latest versions of R and R Studio I was able to load them but seems there is not a 'reshape' version compatible with R 3.2.1 yet.